# Databinding to a DependencyObject on a UserControl

Tags: wpf, data-binding, user-controls, dependency-properties

I have a UserControl, that is laid out like the following:

A DeveloperExpress grid bound to an ObservableCollection called Data:

```
 public ObservableCollection<SummaryData> Data { get; set; }
```

A label with content bound to Cases, which is the first element of the Data collection:

```
<Label FontStyle="Italic" Margin="2" Content="{Binding ElementName=CaseControlUC, Path=Cases.Exposed, TargetNullValue=IAmNull, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

where:

```
        public SummaryData Cases { get; set; }
    private void LoadExampleDataIntoSummaryGrid()
    {
        Cases = new SummaryData() { Caption = "Cases", Exposed = "A", Unexposed = "B" };
        Data.Add(Cases);
        Data.Add(new SummaryData() { Caption = "Controls", Exposed = "C", Unexposed = "D" });
    }
```

And, the code for SummaryData:

```
public class SummaryData : DependencyObject
    {
        public string Caption { get; set; }


        public static readonly DependencyProperty ExposedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ExposedValue",
                                                                                                             typeof(string),
                                                                                                             typeof(SummaryData),
                                                                                                             new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

        public string Exposed
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(ExposedProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(ExposedProperty, value);
            }
        }



        public static readonly DependencyProperty UnexposedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("UnexposedValue",
                                                                                                             typeof(string),
                                                                                                             typeof(SummaryData),
                                                                                                             new UIPropertyMetadata(null));


        public string Unexposed
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(UnexposedProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(UnexposedProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public string Total
        {
            get
            {
                int exposed;
                int unexposed;
                if (Int32.TryParse(Exposed, out exposed) && Int32.TryParse(Unexposed, out unexposed))
                {
                    return (exposed + unexposed).ToString();
                }
                return String.Format("{0} + {1}", Exposed, Unexposed);
            }
        }
    }
```

Note that "Exposed" and "Unexposed" are both DependencyProperties on a DependencyObject.

My problem is that, when I use the Grid to update the Cases-object (and, I know it is indeed updated by using the debugger) the change is not reflected in the label. I've checked, and the output window shows no databinding-errors.
Furthermore, if I revert to having Exposed as a regular property, the initial value is read just fine (though updates aren't reflected, ofc.)

I've also tried inserting a Converter in the databinding (just a NOP converter that returns whatever it is given), and it is indeed never called...

Any tips pit there? :)

Answer (score 1):

In your `Exposed` dependency property declaration, you have specified the name of the property incorrectly, "ExposedValue", rather than "Exposed".

Comment: AFAIK the string-parameter is just the free-text name of the dependency property, and as such I am free to call it whatever I want?
Anyway, I've tried changing it, but unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: Do you have a complete example available for download that recreates the problem? Typically, for model types such as SummaryData, you would implement INotifyPropertyChanged, rather than using dependency properties, because that ties you into WPF and the model can't be reused on other platforms.

Comment: I just managed to get it working an hour or so ago - it was a COMPLETE brainfart, that I am embarassed that I posted here to begin with... I was creating the item I databind to *after* the InitializeComponent() call in my UserControl's constructor, which meant I was trying to databind to null, and of course when I then updated the values once the item was created, well, the databinding had already failed! 

Thanks so much for your help, though!